# How can I adjust my slicers to only impact a specific value in a column on my table?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I'd like to select a Driver from the column and have the slicers only change the "FC numbers" on the right side of my table. For example, if I select ENGA under driver and want to adjust their "FC Miles" slicer to 7,238, how I do prevent it from adjusting TTMA and WVAD "FC Miles" as well?

I've tried to add filter to the slicers but it will remove the others from the table. Or it will assign the same value when I unfilter[image]

Comment: You already asked the same question 3 days ago with 2 close votes, because you've not been able to make yourself clear.

Comment: ENGA, TTMA, and WVAD are drivers with direction relation to the data in "TGT Utl and BGT Utl".  The FC's are essentially forecast based off the data with "X" adjustment from the slicers. Ideally would like to see the delta for only one driver while still viewing the others unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can filter the underlying data table down to the row level only, but you can't break rows and filter single elements. The slicers you apply on the different columns add up to each other, even until there is no matching row left.

This is why they also impact each other. You can stop that by editing the slicer interactions in the *Format* tab, but that won't solve your question.

You don't have a technical problem, but a logical problem that you have to think through.